# HTTP Video Server Seek

Tags: http, video, server, video-streaming

I'm building an HTTP Server to serve video streams.  I have gotten the basics to work, but what headers or query params do I tell the server listen to so that I may have basic seeking support?

Comment: The server doesn't do anything except properly respond to HTTP range requests.

Comment: @szatmary What do those requests look like?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Comment: @Brad This is what I was looking for.  If you do an answer I'll accept it.